# Symfony 6 - Access CollectionType fields in Twig Template

Tags: forms, symfony, collections, symfony-forms

I have a Symfony 6 project, where I us a CollectionType in a Form.

This CollectionType is called "variants" and has three fields. Lets call them:

- Field_1
- Field_2
- Field_3

If I render this CollectionType in my Twig template with `{{form_row(form.variants)}}` all three fields of the CollectionType are rendered underneith.

However, I would like to to separate each of the fields of the CollectionType in a own column next to each other. But how dow I access the fields?

I have tried to access the fields via `{{form_row(form.variants.Field_1)}}` but obviously that did not work.

I am happy about any ideas :)

Comment: A `CollectionType` contains a collection. The collection doesn't have a `Field1` option but should have children or be an iterable. Try to loop on it.

Comment: What I meant is that the fields in the CollectionType are named so, Field_1, Field_2 and Field_3. This CollectionType is now a form field of another FormType, which I display in Twig. In order to display the individual "fields" of the CollectionType side by side, I just have to address them somehow and I don't know how. How would I iterate over them? :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you were close.

CollectionType is an array - as it can hold multiple sets of the type.
If you only have one set try

```
{{ form_row(form.variants[0].Field_1) }}
{{ form_row(form.variants[0].Field_2) }}
{{ form_row(form.variants[0].Field_3) }}
```

The for method:

```
{% for variant in form.variants %}
 {{ form_row(variant.Field_1) }}
 {{ form_row(variant.Field_2) }}
 {{ form_row(variant.Field_3) }}  
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Or you can use a for block to do this better ;)

Comment: I see, thanks for the help @Rufinus! :)

@vinceAmstoutz How would I achieve this with a for block?^^

Comment: @Schwaluck - i added a example with an loop.

Comment: @schwaluck exactly like Rufinus do that and your last post :)

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to Rufinus again.

I used that information and the remark from vinceAmstoutz and did the creation in a foor loop:

```
{% for variant in form.variants %} 
<div class="row">
       <div class="col">
            {{ form_row(variant.Field_1) }}
       </div>
       <div class="col">
            {{ form_row(variant.Field_2) }}
       </div>
       <div class="col">
            {{ form_row(variant.Field_3) }}
       </div>      
</div>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: came to late to add the for loop example - gald you figured it out yourself - i think you where just missing the additional array in your earilier tries.

Comment: With pleasure and I didn't have the time to go on my PC to send it to you either. Congratulations to you! @schwaluck